How can I make discord application commands Sync instantly in Discord.py?
I am trying to create a moderation bot that is able to have slash commands and I only need it for one server. I can't figure out why the commands are not syncing at all and I do want them to sync instantly. Another issue I had was clearing previous commands that I am not using. The old commands that somehow worked are still there.
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Bot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        intents = discord.Intents.default()
        intents.message_content = True
        super().__init__(command_prefix='?', intents=intents)

    async def setup_hook(self):
        await self.tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=12345678910)) # I didn't include the id for security reasons.
        print(f"Synced slash commands for {self.user}.")

    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        await ctx.reply(str(error), ephemeral=True)

bot = Bot()

@bot.hybrid_command(name="test", with_app_command=True, description="Testing")
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def test(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.defer(ephemeral=True)
    await ctx.reply("hi!")

bot_token = 'bot-token-here' # I didn't include the token for security reasons.

bot.run(bot_token)

I tried changing the code and running different versions. I even tried @bot.command and nothing seems to work.

Testing & Fix

After testing your code ?test would work and syncing globally will work however, as you described the application command would not be updated on discord if you target a specific guild.
Below is a fix:
guild = await bot.fetch_guild(GUILD_ID)
bot.tree.copy_global_to(guild=guild)
await self.tree.sync(guild=guild)
print(f"Synced slash commands for {self.user}.")

So you are fetching the guild with the guild_ID instead of using a discord.Object then you are pushing all the global commands to a specific guild. Documentation for bot.tree.copy_global_to(...) found here.
Then finally you are doing the tree sync to the specific guild, passing it in as the argument in self.tree.sync.
Syncing Commands

I would suggest creating a command which only you can execute to sync your commands - in order to avoid getting rate limited, also you only need to sync when creating or deleting application commands.
# an example of a global sync command
@bot.tree.command(name='sync', description='Owner only')
async def sync(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    if str(interaction.user.id) == YOUR_ID:
        await client.tree.sync()
        await interaction.response.send_message('Synced Successfully')
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message('You must be the owner to use this command!')

.
